# Build a deb package without changing the repository name

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

I want to build my deb package out of a little C program I wrote a while ago.
Was was able to do it but i had to rename the source folder to do it.

I renamed it from myprogramm to myprogram-1.0 and than create myprogram_1.0.orig.tar.gz out of it.

Is there a way to do build the package without renaming the source folder ?

I use `debuild -us -uc` to actually build the package.

This is my debian/rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/myprogramm/usr
```

debian/control:

```
Source: myprogram
Maintainer:  name <name@name>
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)

Package: myprogram
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: myprogram is a command line tool to create html templates.
```

debian/changelog:

```
myprogram (1.0-1) UNRELEASED; urgency=medium

* Initial release. 

-- name <name@name>  Wed, 05 Sep 2018 11:32:17 +0200
```

Thx for your help.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Care to share a bit more on your setup? Which tools are you using?

Comment: What is "the repository folder"?

Comment: The folder of the cloned git. I changed the post to make it clear now.

Comment: Do you have a proper `debian/changelog`? Does using `debuild -b -us -uc` make any difference?

Comment: I added the changelog. Should I use `debuild -b -us -uc` on the renamed source folder, or the original one?